# Can condor display results through STDOUT

Tags: condor

I am streaming my output back to submit machine with this two commands:

```
stream_output = True
output = out.txt
```

Is it possible to stream output to stdout on submit machine instead to file out.txt?

Comment: You want to stream to stdout of what? After you run `condor_submit` you are back at your shell prompt. Do you just want to tail the output so you can see it as it happens live?

Answer (score 0):

After you submit your job using `condor_submit` there is nothing to stream stdout to. However, you can watch stdout by either using `stream_output` and `tail -f out.txt` or, alternatively if you do not want to use `stream_output` you can use `condor_tail -f` to watch stdout of the running job on the execute node.